# Insertion in Red-Black tree

Tags: python, data-structures, red-black-tree

I am trying to implement a Red-Black tree as per the CLRS textbook. The TreeNode class defines the nodes and has got functions for defining the nodes, determining whether the node is a right node or a left node. The class BST is for the tree. When the program is run(printing in inorder) it enters an infinite loop and the node self.nil is not detected. This leads me to suspect that the problem is in "insertFix" method. I am probably messing up somewhere there.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,val,left = None,right = None, parent = None,color = None):
        self.val = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right
        self.parent = parent
        self.color = color

    def hasLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def hasRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def isLeftChild(self):
        return (self.parent and (self.parent.leftChild == self))

    def isRightChild(self):
        return (self.parent and (self.parent.rightChild == self))

class BST(TreeNode):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0
        self.nil = TreeNode(None)
        self.nil.color = "black"

    def addNode(self,val):
        self.size += 1
        y = self.nil
        x = self.root
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = TreeNode(val,self.nil,self.nil,self.nil,"black")
        else:
            z = TreeNode(val,self.nil,self.nil, None, "red")
            while x!=self.nil:
                y = x
                if z.val < x.val:
                    x = x.hasLeftChild()
                else:
                    x = x.hasRightChild()
            z.parent = y 
            if y == self.nil:
                self.root = z
            elif z.val < y.val:
                y.leftChild = z
            else:
                y.rightChild = z
            self.treeInsFixer(z)

    def treeInsFixer(self,z):
        while z.parent.color == "red":
            if z.parent == z.parent.parent.leftChild:
                y = z.parent.parent.rightChild
                if y.color == "red":
                    z.parent.color = "black"
                    y.color = "black"
                    z.parent.parent.color = "red"
                    z = z.parent.parent
                else:
                    if z == z.parent.rightChild:
                        z = z.parent
                        self.leftRotate(z)
                    z.parent.color = "black"
                    z.parent.parent.color = "red"
                    self.rightRotate(z.parent.parent)
            elif z.parent == z.parent.parent.rightChild:
                y = z.parent.parent.leftChild
                if y.color == "red":
                    z.parent.color = "black"
                    y.color = "black"
                    z.parent.parent.color = "red"
                    z = z.parent.parent
                else:
                    if z == z.parent.leftChild:
                        z = z.parent
                        self.rightRotate(z)
                    z.parent.color = "black"
                    z.parent.parent.color = "red"
                    self.leftRotate(z.parent.parent)
        self.root.color = "black"               

    def leftRotate(self,x):
        y = x.rightChild
        x.rightChild = y.leftChild
        if y.leftChild != self.nil:
            y.leftChild.parent = x
        y.parent = x.parent
        if x.parent == self.nil:
            self.root = y
        elif x == x.isLeftChild():
            x.parent.leftChild = y
        else:
            x.parent.rightChild = y
        y.leftChild = x
        x.parent = y

    def rightRotate(self,x): 
        y = x.leftChild
        x.leftChild = y.rightChild
        if y.rightChild != self.nil:
            y.rightChild.parent = x
        y.parent = x.parent
        if x.parent == self.nil:
            self.root = y 
        elif x == x.isRightChild():
            x.parent.rightChild = y
        else:
            x.parent.leftChild = y
        y.rightChild = x 
        x.parent = y

    def inOrder(self,x):
        if(x!=self.nil):
            self.inOrder(x.leftChild)
            print(x.val, x.color)
            self.inOrder(x.rightChild)



a = BST()
a.addNode(5)
a.addNode(7)
a.addNode(4)
a.addNode(14)
a.addNode(6)
a.addNode(11)
a.addNode(9)
a.addNode(17)
a.addNode(2)
a.addNode(10)
a.addNode(8)
a.inOrder(a.root)
```

I know this is a lot of code to go throught but I am totally at my wits end trying to figure out the problem. Any suggestion will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here:

```
def inOrder(self,x):
    if(x!=self.nil):
        self.inOrder(x.leftChild)
        print(x.val, x.color)
        self.inOrder(x.rightChild)
```

It is always `True`. Because Python does this by comparing the ids of the objects until you override `__eq__` `__cmp__` `__ne__` to compare Node's value.

- [Good article](http://push.cx/2006/equality-for-python)
- [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)